# Determinant of a generalized Pascal matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, combinatorics, matrices, determinant

Let $M$ denote the infinite matrix defined recursively by

$$
M_{ij} = 
\begin{cases}
  1, &  \text{if } i=1 \text{ and } j=1; \\
  aM_{i-1,j}+bM_{i,j-1}+cM_{i-1,j-1}, & \mbox{otherwise}.\\ \end{cases}
$$
($M_{i,0}$ and $M_{0,j}$ are both defined to be $0$.)

(*Added*: I just discovered that the numbers in the $M$ matrix are called *weighted Delannoy numbers*.)

Let $M_n$ denote the $n \times n$ upper-left submatrix of $M$.

For example, with $a = b = c = 1$,

$M_1 = \begin{bmatrix} 1 \end{bmatrix}$, $M_2= \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 1 \\ 1 & 3 \end{bmatrix}$, and $M_3 = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 1 & 1 \\ 1 & 3 & 5 \\ 1 & 5 & 13 \end{bmatrix}$, and $M_4 = \begin{bmatrix}
    1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
    1 & 3 & 5 & 7 \\
    1 & 5 & 13 & 25 \\
    1 & 7 & 25 & 63
   \end{bmatrix}.$

A few years ago one of my students proved, by induction, that $$\det M_n = (ab+c)^{n(n-1)/2}.$$
My question is

> Is there a noninductive proof that $\det M_n = (ab+c)^{n(n-1)/2}$ that gives more insight into why the determinant works out so nicely?

For example, when $a = b = 1$, $c = 0$, $M$ is the symmetric [Pascal matrix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pascal_matrix).  I've seen more than one way to prove that $\det M_n = 1$ in this case.  For example, [Edelman and Strang give four proofs](http://web.mit.edu/18.06/www/Essays/pascal-work.pdf) of an LU-decomposition that does it.  I also once saw, at a conference, a combinatorial proof using the interpretation of the determinant in terms of nonintersecting paths in a directed graph.  (I think the talk was given by Art Benjamin, but it was several years ago, and I may be misremembering.)  So I know that there are some nice proofs in the special case of the Pascal matrix.  But what about the general case?

Comment: In addition to the recent article by Ik-Pyo Kim cited by Sivaram Ambikasaran, I just came across an 2002 [paper](http://www.mat.univie.ac.at/~slc/wpapers/s47kratt.html) by Christian Krattenthaler that solves this problem (its Theorem 1 on page 2, which is for $a=b=1$ but that can easily be seen to imply the general formula; on the other hand the initial row/column are taken of a more general form there). It appears that Roland Bacher also investigated this problem around the same time.

Comment: @Marc: See also [this paper](http://www.fmf.uni-lj.si/~petkovsek/PascalDeterminants.pdf) by Zakrajšek and Petkovšek, which appears to build on the work by Krattenthaler and Bacher.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**EDIT**:

So after all the effort I put in couple of days back to prove this, I found out today that this result was already published earlier this year. The article is "LDU decomposition of an extension matrix of the Pascal matrix," by Ik-Pyo Kim (*Linear Algebra and Its Applications* 434(10) 2187-2196, 2011) and can be found [here](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0024379510006634).

---

The $LU$ factorization of $M_{n+1}$ is given below. Let $x$ be such that $x^2 = 1 + \frac{c}{ab}$. Then we have that $$M_{n+1} = L_{n+1} U_{n+1}$$ where
$$\small L_{n+1} = \begin{bmatrix}1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \cdots & 0 & 0\\a & ax & 0 & 0 & 0 & \cdots & 0 & 0\\ a^2 & 2a^2x & a^2x^2 & 0 & 0 & \cdots & 0 & 0\\ a^3 & 3a^3x & 3a^3x^2 & a^3x^3 & 0 & \cdots & 0 & 0\\ a^4 & 4a^4x & 6a^4x^2 & 4a^4x^3 & a^4x^4 & \cdots & 0 & 0\\ \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots  & \ddots  & \vdots & \vdots\\ \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots  & \cdots  & \ddots & \vdots \\ a^n & \binom{n}{1}a^nx^1  & \binom{n}{2}a^nx^2 & \binom{n}{3}a^nx^3 & \binom{n}{4}a^nx^4  & \cdots  & \binom{n}{n-1}a^nx^{n-1} & a^nx^n \end{bmatrix}$$

$$\small U_{n+1}^T = \begin{bmatrix}1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \cdots & 0 & 0\\b & bx & 0 & 0 & 0 & \cdots & 0 & 0\\ b^2 & 2b^2x & b^2x^2 & 0 & 0 & \cdots & 0 & 0\\ b^3 & 3b^3x & 3b^3x^2 & b^3x^3 & 0 & \cdots & 0 & 0\\ b^4 & 4b^4x & 6b^4x^2 & 4b^4x^3 & b^4x^4 & \cdots & 0 & 0\\ \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots  & \ddots  & \vdots & \vdots\\ \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots  & \cdots  & \ddots & \vdots \\ b^n & \binom{n}{1}b^nx^1  & \binom{n}{2}b^nx^2 & \binom{n}{3}b^nx^3 & \binom{n}{4}b^nx^4  & \cdots  & \binom{n}{n-1}b^nx^{n-1} & b^nx^n \end{bmatrix}$$

This gives us $\det(L_n) = (ax)^{\frac{n(n-1)}{2}}$ and $\det(U_n) = (bx)^{\frac{n(n-1)}{2}}$.

Hence, $\det(M_n) = (ax)^{\frac{n(n-1)}{2}}(bx)^{\frac{n(n-1)}{2}} = (abx^2)^{\frac{n(n-1)}{2}} = (ab+c)^{\frac{n(n-1)}{2}}$.

Also note that $$L_n = A_n X_n$$ and $$U_n^T = B_n X_n$$ where $$A_{n+1} = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \cdots & 0 & 0\\ 0 & a & 0 & 0 & 0 & \cdots & 0 & 0\\ 0 & 0 & a^2 & 0 & 0 & \cdots & 0 & 0\\ 0 & 0 & 0 & a^3 & 0 & \cdots & 0 & 0\\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & a^4 & \cdots & 0 & 0\\ \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots & \vdots\\ \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \cdots & \ddots & \vdots\\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0& \cdots & 0 & a^n\\ \end{bmatrix}$$
$$B_{n+1} = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \cdots & 0 & 0\\ 0 & b & 0 & 0 & 0 & \cdots & 0 & 0\\ 0 & 0 & b^2 & 0 & 0 & \cdots & 0 & 0\\ 0 & 0 & 0 & b^3 & 0 & \cdots & 0 & 0\\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & b^4 & \cdots & 0 & 0\\ \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots & \vdots\\ \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \cdots & \ddots & \vdots\\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0& \cdots & 0 & b^n\\ \end{bmatrix}$$
$$X_{n+1} = \begin{bmatrix}1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \cdots & 0 & 0\\1 & x & 0 & 0 & 0 & \cdots & 0 & 0\\ 1 & 2x & x^2 & 0 & 0 & \cdots & 0 & 0\\ 1 & 3x & 3x^2 & x^3 & 0 & \cdots & 0 & 0\\ 1 & 4x & 6x^2 & 4x^3 & x^4 & \cdots & 0 & 0\\ \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots  & \ddots  & \vdots & \vdots\\ \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots  & \cdots  & \ddots & \vdots \\ 1 & \binom{n}{1}x^1  & \binom{n}{2}x^2 & \binom{n}{3}x^3 & \binom{n}{4}x^4  & \cdots  & \binom{n}{n-1}x^{n-1} & x^n \end{bmatrix}$$
Further $X_n$ can be written as $C_n \tilde{X}_n$ where
$$C_{n+1} = \begin{bmatrix}1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \cdots & 0 & 0\\1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \cdots & 0 & 0\\ 1 & 2 & 1 & 0 & 0 & \cdots & 0 & 0\\ 1 & 3 & 3 & 1 & 0 & \cdots & 0 & 0\\ 1 & 4 & 6 & 4 & 1 & \cdots & 0 & 0\\ \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots  & \ddots  & \vdots & \vdots\\ \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots  & \cdots  & \ddots & \vdots \\ 1 & \binom{n}{1}  & \binom{n}{2} & \binom{n}{3} & \binom{n}{4}  & \cdots  & \binom{n}{n-1} & 1 \end{bmatrix}$$ and $$\tilde{X}_{n+1} = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \cdots & 0 & 0\\ 0 & x & 0 & 0 & 0 & \cdots & 0 & 0\\ 0 & 0 & x^2 & 0 & 0 & \cdots & 0 & 0\\ 0 & 0 & 0 & x^3 & 0 & \cdots & 0 & 0\\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & x^4 & \cdots & 0 & 0\\ \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots & \vdots\\ \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \cdots & \ddots & \vdots\\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0& \cdots & 0 & x^n\\ \end{bmatrix}$$
$$M_n = A_n C_n \tilde{X}_n^2 C_n^T B_n^T$$
Setting $D_n = \tilde{X}_n^2$, we get a nice decomposition for $M_n$ as $$M_n = A_n C_n D_n C_n^T B_n.$$
Note that $A_n,B_n,D_n$ are diagonal matrices where $A_n(i,i) = a^i$,$B_n(i,i) = b^i$ and $D_n(i,i) = \left( 1+\frac{c}{ab} \right)^i$.

$C_n$ is a triangular matrix containing the binomial coefficients where $C_n(i,j) = \left \{ \begin{array}{lr} \binom{i-1}{j-1} & j \leq i\\ 0 & j > i \end{array}\right.$.

---

**EDIT**

I computed this decomposition by the usual $LU$ algorithm. But given that now we have this, it should be possible to reverse engineer other proofs, similar to the proofs for the Pascal's matrix.

---

**Proof**

Let me first write out the proof based on the algorithm I used to construct these $L$ and $U$ factors.

Consider the elimination matrix $$E_{n+1}^y = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \cdots\\
-y & 1 & 0 & 0 & \cdots\\
0 & -y & 1 & 0 & \cdots\\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \cdots\\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & -y & 1
\end{pmatrix}$$

Note that $E_{n+1}^a L_{n+1} = \begin{pmatrix}1 & 0\\ 0 & ax L_n \end{pmatrix}$ and $E_{n+1}^b U_{n+1}^T = \begin{pmatrix}1 & 0\\ 0 & bx U_n^T \end{pmatrix}$

Hence, $E_{n+1}^a L_{n+1} U_{n+1} (E_{n+1}^b )^T = \begin{pmatrix}1 & 0\\ 0 & abx^2 M_n \end{pmatrix}$.

Our hope is that the above matrix should match with $E_{n+1}^a M_{n+1} (E_{n+1}^b)^T$.

Consider the $(i,j)^{th}$ entry of $E_{n+1}^a M_{n+1}$. This is $M_{n+1}(i,j)-a M_{n+1}(i-1,j)$.

Now the $(i,j)^{th}$ entry of $E_{n+1}^a M_{n+1} (E_{n+1}^b)^T$ is 
$\begin{align}
M_{n+1}(i,j)-a M_{n+1}(i-1,j) -b \left( M_{n+1}(i,j-1)-a M_{n+1}(i-1,j-1) \right)\\
= M_{n+1}(i,j) - a M_{n+1}(i-1,j) -b M_{n+1}(i,j-1) + ab M_{n+1}(i-1,j-1) \\
= \left( M_{n+1}(i,j) - a M_{n+1}(i-1,j) -b M_{n+1}(i,j-1) \right) + ab M_{n+1}(i-1,j-1) \\
= c M_{n+1}(i-1,j-1) + ab M_{n+1}(i-1,j-1) = abx^2 M_{n+1}(i-1,j-1)
\end{align}$

But $M_{n+1}(i-1,j-1) = M_n(i-1,j-1)$. Hence, we get that $$M_{n+1}(i,j)-a M_{n+1}(i-1,j) -b \left( M_{n+1}(i,j-1)-a M_{n+1}(i-1,j-1) \right) = abx^2 M_{n}(i-1,j-1).$$

Hence, coupling with induction we get the complete proof. (Note that the matrix $E_n^y$ is always invertible enabling us to conclude what we want.)

---

**Proof** of the decomposition $M_n = A_n C_n D_n C_n^T B_n$ based on a combinatorial argument.

Let us first fix what we are counting.

Consider a positive integer lattice. Starting at a point $(m,n)$ the allowed options to move are either horizontal towards right to $(m+1,n)$ (or) vertical towards top to $(m,n+1)$ (or) diagonal towards right top $(m+1,n+1)$.

The cost for a horizontal movement is $a$, the cost for a vertical movement is $b$ and the cost for a diagonal movement is $c$. Further, the total cost of a path is the product of the costs of individual movements i.e. if a path takes $x$ horizontal right movement, $y$ vertical top movements and $z$ diagonal right top movements, the total cost of this path is $a^xb^yc^z$. Note that by this the cost to stay where you are is $1$.

**Claim:** $M(i,j)$ gives the sum of the costs over all paths to move from $(1,1)$ to $(i,j)$.

**Proof:** This immediately follows from the recursive definition of $M(i,j)$. The last step before hitting $(i,j)$, we will be either at $(i-1,j)$ (or) $(i-1,j-1)$ (or) $(i,j-1)$. Hence, the total cost over all paths from $(1,1)$ to $(i,j)$ is $aM(i-1,j) + bM(i,j-1) + cM(i-1,j-1)$.

So all we need to prove is $(A_n C_n D_n C_n^T B_n) (i,j)$ also gives the cost of moving from $(1,1)$ to $(i,j)$. Note that $A_n,B_n,D_n$ are diagonal matrices which essentially means though the product has $4$ summations, they can be collapsed to just one i.e.
$
\begin{align}
(A_n C_n D_n C_n^T B_n) (i,j) & = \sum_{k1} \sum_{k2} \sum_{k3} \sum_{k4} A_n(i,k1) C_n(k1,k2) D_n(k2,k3) C_n(k4,k3) B_n(k4,j)\\
& = \sum_{k1} \sum_{k} \sum_{k4} A_n(i,k1) C_n(k1,k) D_n(k,k) C_n(k4,k) B_n(k4,j)\\
& = \sum_{k} A_n(i,i) C_n(i,k) D_n(k,k) C_n(j,k) B_n(j,j)\\
& = \sum_{k=1}^{\min(i,j)} a^{i-1} \binom{i-1}{k-1} (x^2)^{k-1} \binom{j-1}{k-1} b^{j-1}\\
& = \sum_{k=1}^{\min(i,j)} a^{i-1} \binom{i-1}{k-1} \left( 1 + \frac{c}{ab} \right)^{k-1} \binom{j-1}{k-1} b^{j-1}\\
& = \sum_{k=1}^{\min(i,j)} a^{i-k} \binom{i-1}{k-1} \left( ab + c \right)^{k-1} \binom{j-1}{k-1} b^{j-k}\\
& = \sum_{k=1}^{\min(i,j)} \sum_{r=0}^{k-1} a^{i-k} \binom{i-1}{k-1} \binom{k-1}{r} (ab)^{k-1-r} c^r \binom{j-1}{k-1} b^{j-k}\\
& = \sum_{r=0}^{\min(i,j)-1} a^{i-1-r} b^{j-1-r} c^r \left( \sum_{k=r+1}^{\min(i,j)} \binom{i-1}{k-1} \binom{k-1}{r} \binom{j-1}{k-1} \right)
\end{align}
$
All we need to prove now is that $\displaystyle \left( \sum_{k=r+1}^{\min(i,j)} \binom{i-1}{k-1} \binom{k-1}{r} \binom{j-1}{k-1} \right)$ counts the number of paths with $r$ top right  diagonal movements.

Equivalently, we need to prove that $\displaystyle \left( \sum_{t=0}^{\min(i,j)-r-1} \binom{i-1}{t+r} \binom{t+r}{r} \binom{j-1}{t+r} \right)$ counts the number of paths with $r$ top right  diagonal movements.

Counting the number of paths from $(1,1)$ to $(i,j)$ with $r$ top right diagonal movements. If we denote the right horizontal movement by $h$, top vertical movement by $v$ and top right diagonal movement by $d$, then the path we are interested in contains $(i-1-r)$ $h$'s, $(j-1-r)$ $v$'s and $(r)$ $d$'s. Any arrangement of this gives us the desired path. Hence, the total number of paths from $(1,1)$ to $(i,j)$ with $r$ top right diagonal movements is $$\frac{(i+j-r-2)!}{(i-1-r)!(j-1-r)!r!}.$$

Hence all we need to prove is that $$\displaystyle \sum_{t=0}^{\min(i,j)-r-1} \binom{i-1}{t+r} \binom{t+r}{r} \binom{j-1}{t+r} = \frac{(i+j-r-2)!}{(i-1-r)!(j-1-r)!r!}$$

**Claim:**$\displaystyle \sum_{t=0}^{\min(i,j)-r-1} \binom{i-1}{t+r} \binom{t+r}{r} \binom{j-1}{t+r} = \frac{(i+j-r-2)!}{(i-1-r)!(j-1-r)!r!}$

First note that $\displaystyle \binom{i-1}{t+r} \binom{t+r}{r} = \binom{i-1}{r} \binom{i-1-r}{t}$.

(Can be proved algebraically or through a combinatorial argument of choosing $3$ sets of things in different orders.)

Hence, we get that $$\displaystyle \sum_{t=0}^{\min(i,j)-r-1} \binom{i-1}{t+r} \binom{t+r}{r} \binom{j-1}{t+r} = \binom{i-1}{r} \sum_{t=0}^{\min(i,j)-r-1} \binom{i-1-r}{t} \binom{j-1}{t+r}$$

Now $\displaystyle \sum_{t=0}^{\min(i,j)-r-1} \binom{i-1-r}{t} \binom{j-1}{t+r} = \sum_{t=0}^{\min(i,j)-r-1} \binom{i-1-r}{t} \binom{j-1}{j-1-t+r} = \binom{i+j-r-2}{j-r-1}$

In the first step above, the first step is nothing but $\binom{n}{r} = \binom{n}{n-r}$ while the second step splits things into two different sets and does the same counting.

Hence, we get that $$\displaystyle \sum_{t=0}^{\min(i,j)-r-1} \binom{i-1}{t+r} \binom{t+r}{r} \binom{j-1}{t+r} = \binom{i-1}{r} \binom{i+j-r-2}{j-r-1}$$

But $\displaystyle \binom{i-1}{r} \binom{i+j-r-2}{j-r-1} = \frac{(i+j-r-2)!}{(i-1-r)!(j-1-r)!r!}$ which can be seen through direct algebra or again a combinatorial argument which relies on picking things in different order.

Hence, we get that $\displaystyle \sum_{t=0}^{\min(i,j)-r-1} \binom{i-1}{t+r} \binom{t+r}{r} \binom{j-1}{t+r} = \frac{(i+j-r-2)!}{(i-1-r)!(j-1-r)!r!}$.

This completes the combinatorial proof.

Comment: @MikeSpivey: Correct. I used the usual LU decomposition to identify the underlying pattern and have not proved it rigorously yet. I think I have a combinatorial argument, which is the same as Strang's to get to decomposition in terms of $A_n,B_n,C_n$ and $D_n$, with diagonals included. If we take $x$ horizontal, $y$ vertical and $z$ diagonal paths in a square, the cost of the path is given by $a^xb^yc^z$. $M_n(i,j)$ counts the total cost across all paths. This $(i,j)$ term can also be expressed in terms of coefficients of the matrices $A_n,B_n,C_n$ and $D_n$.

Comment: @MikeSpivey: Getting the LU directly by a combinatorial argument seems to be messy since the coefficients involve $\sqrt{}$'s which is hard to interpret for me in a combinatorial sense. Also, the term $\frac{c}{ab}$ appears a path horizontal and vertical can be replaced by a diagonal path and hence the cost $ab$ gets replaced by $c$. Anyway I will write out all these in the answers and hope that I will be able to get a combinatorial interpretation for the product in terms of $A_n,B_n,C_n$ and $D_n$. But first I need to go to my lab. Once I am there, I will spend the rest of the day on this :).

Comment: @MikeSpivey: I think the proof is now done. The combinatorial argument is also almost done though I am not clear how to prove the last statement I have mentioned. I shall finish it later tonight or tomorrow. In the meantime, your comments are welcome.

Comment: @MikeSpivey: Hope the proof is complete now. Just as an additional generalization, I realize the problem can be further generalized by assuming the transition at every step is not constant i.e. replace $a$ by $a_i$, $b$ by $b_j$ and  $c$ by $c_{ij}$. I don't see where the arguments will break down. For instance, terms like $a^k$ will be replaced by terms like $\prod_{i=1}^{k} a_i$ and similar terms.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/1873/discussion-between-sivaram-ambikasaran-and-mike-spivey)

Comment: @MikeSpivey: I am wondering if there is any difference between the first two proofs mentioned in Strang's paper? The first proof makes use of the identity $\sum_k \binom{i}{k} \binom{j}{k} = \binom{i+j}{i}$ while the second proof essentially gives a combinatorial proof of the identity.

Comment: Again, thank you, Sivaram.  I wish I could upvote this more than once.

Comment: @Sivaram Ambikasaran: I've tried to extract the gist of this argument in my answer, but I must admit not having had the stamina to read through all the details that are given here. I hope it corresponds to what you did.

Comment: could you explain the differences between LU decomposition  and **LDU** decomposition? I just can't get it.

Answer (score 6):

Inspired by the solution of Sivaram Ambikasaran, I would just like to furnish some concision. Given
$$
M_{i,j} = 
\begin{cases}
  a^{i-1}b^{j-1} &  \text{if } i=1 \text{ or } j=1, \\
  aM_{i-1,j}+bM_{i,j-1}+cM_{i-1,j-1} & \mbox{if }i>1 \text{ and } j>1,\\ \end{cases}
$$
one may (inspired by what is said in the Edelman-Strang paper) start subtracting from each row (except the first) $a$ times the previous row. This is to be done simultaneously, or working from the bottom up, so that it is the *original* value of the row that is subtracted. This amounts to left-multiplying by the elimination matrix $E_{-a}$ with diagonal entries $1$ and subdiagonal entries $-a$. One obtains a matrix $M'$ given by 
$$
M'_{i,j} = 
\begin{cases}
  b^{j-1} & \text{if } i=1, \\
  M_{i,j}-aM_{i-1,j} & \mbox{if }i>1.\\ \end{cases}
$$
The latter expression is $0$ if $j=1$, and otherwise
$$
  M'_{i,j} = bM_{i,j-1}+cM_{i-1,j-1}\qquad\text{if }i,j>1
$$
using the recursion defining $M$. Now proceed similarly by columns, right-multiplying by the transpose $E_{-b}^\top$ of $E_{-b}$, giving a new matrix $M''$ given by
$$
M''_{i,j} = 
\begin{cases}
  \delta_{i,j} & \text{if } j=1, \\
  M'_{i,j}-bM'_{i,j-1} & \mbox{if }j>1.\\ \end{cases}
$$
The latter expression is $0$ if $i=1$, and otherwise
$$\begin{align}
  M''_{i,j} &= bM_{i,j-1}+cM_{i-1,j-1}-b(M_{i,j-1}-aM_{i-1,j-1})\\
           & =(ab+c)M_{i-1,j-1}
\end{align}\qquad\text{if }i,j>1,
$$
using the two expressions for $M'_{i,j}$ given above. In other words one has in block form
$$
  M''=\begin{pmatrix}1&0\\ 0&(ab+c)M_{(n-1)}\end{pmatrix}
$$
where $M_{(n-1)}$ is the $(n-1)\times(n-1)$ top-left submatrix of $M$, which is its counterpart of size one less. Therefore
$$
  \det M_{(n)} = \det M = \det M''= (ab+c)^{n-1} \det M_{(n-1)}
$$
from which it follows by induction that $\det M=(ab+c)^{\tbinom{n}2}$.

The scalar multplication of $M_{(n-1)}$ by $ab+c$ can of course be realised as the multiplication by a multiple of the identity matrix, which commutes with with the matrices obtained in a recursive decomposition of $M_{(n-1)}$. It is then easy to conclude that one has a decomposition
$$
  M_{(n)} = L_{(n)} D_{(n)} U_{(n)}
$$
where $D_{(n)}$ is diagonal with entries $(D_{(n)})_{i,i}=(ab+c)^{i-1}$ and $L_{(n)}$ and $U_{(n)}$ are unitriangular and therefore have determinant $1$. Their explicit form can be obtained from the recurrences
$$
  L_{(n)} = (E_{-a})^{-1}\cdot \begin{pmatrix}1&0\\ 0&L_{(n-1)}\end{pmatrix},
  \qquad
  U_{(n)} = \begin{pmatrix}1&0\\ 0&U_{(n-1)}\end{pmatrix}\cdot(E_{-b}^\top)^{-1},
$$
which can easily found to be solved by $(L_{(n)})_{i,j}=\binom{i-1}{j-1}a^{i-j}$ and $(U_{(n)})_{i,j}=\binom{j-1}{i-1}b^{j-i}$, either using $((E_{-a})^{-1})_{i,j}=a^{i-j}$ or by solving first $((L_{(n)})^{-1})_{i,j}=\binom{i-1}{j-1}(-a)^{i-j}$.

Comment: +1.  And thanks for taking the time to write this up, Marc.

Answer (score 1):

This is not an answer but rather a comment of Sivaram's answer.
*[update] I've to correct the numerical examples because I used a slightly distorted version of* ***M***. *But this does not affect the basic idea of using the LDU-decompostion instead of the LU-decomposition. Finally, this is now not much more than a slight optimization of Sivaram's ansatz*

If I decompose into $\small L \cdot D \cdot U $ instead, where ***D*** is diagonal, then the pattern of the construction of the factors ***L*** and ***U*** is more "simple"(contains only *a* resp. *b*) but their diagonals are 1 and so can be neglected for the determinant. So we need only the determinant of ***D***. Then we find, that ***D*** can be described by
$\qquad \small D=[1,c+ab, (c+ab)^2, (c+ab)^3,\ldots ,(c+ab)^{n-1} ] = dV(c+ab,n) $

and the determinant for matrix-size *n x n* is then the product of these terms up to *n-1* by an obvious simple expression. Again the found pattern in the **LDU**-decomposition must be proven, but the approach might possibly allow a shorter path...

**[added]** : The actual LDU-decomposition can be written as

$\qquad \small M = P^{\quad a} \cdot \quad dV(c+ab) \cdot (P^{\quad b} \sim )$

where ***P*** is the lower triangular Pascalmatrix,  "~" means the transpose and ***dV(x)*** is the diagonalmatrix containing the consecutive powers of its argument *x* beginning at $\small x^0 $

(remark: I also prefer this ***LDU*** often because it avoids introducing sqaures and/or squareroots, like for instance does the cholesky-decomposition for the symmetric case)

---

in case your software has a ***LDU***-decomposition not available, here is some code usable for Pari/GP

```
 LDU(Y) = local(dim=#Y, D, MR, ML, dx); \\ Y must be square, 
       \\ no errorchecks in     demo-documentation
 D=matrix(dim,dim); MR=matid(dim); ML=matid(dim);
 for(p=1,dim, 
   D[p,p]=(dx=Y[p,p]);
   for(c=p+1,dim,
        MR[p,c]=if(dx==0,0,Y[p,c]/dx)
       );
   for(r=p+1,dim, 
        ML[r,p]=if(dx==0,0,Y[r,p]/dx)
      );
   for(r=p+1,dim,
      for(c=p+1,dim,
            Y[r,c]-=ML[r,p]*dx*MR[p,c]
      ));
  );
return([ML,D,MR]);
```

The matrix ***L*** has the form [now corrected!] $\small L = P^a $

$\small \begin{array} {lllll}
 1 & . & . & . & . & . \\
 a & 1 & . & . & . & . \\
 a^2 & 2a & 1 & . & . & . \\
 a^3 & 3a^2 & 3a & 1 & . & . \\
 a^4 & 4a^3 & 6a^2 & 4a & 1 & . \\
 a^5 & 5a^4 & 10a^3 & 10a^2 & 5a & 1
 \end{array} $

while ***U*** is simply the transposed and *a* replaced by *b*.

---

[update]
Here is the Pari/GP code to generate the matrix ***M*** (corrected) and the call for the LDU-decomposition:

```
M = matrix(6,6,r,c); for(r=1,6,M[r,1]='a^(r-1)); for(c=1,6,M[1,c]='b^(r-1));
    for(r=2,rows(M),for(c=2,cols(M),M[r,c]='a*M[r-1,c]+'b*M[r,c-1]+'c*M[r-1,c-1]))
M_ldu = LDU(M); L=M_ldu[1];D=diag(M_ldu[2]);U=M_ldu[3];
print (D)  \\ check the diagonal-component
%1164 = [1,
         c + a*b ,
         c^2 + 2*b*a*c + b^2*a^2,
         ... (snipped) ] ~
```

Comment: Are you sure about the $a+b+c-1$ in your formula for $D[1]$? The only kind of factor that should end up in the determinant is $ab+c$, and this excludes that any diagonal factor of $M$ should have a coefficient of the form you give.

Comment: Marc, I've checked that formula a couple of times; I don't see any error. If I recombine *L.D.U* I get the original matrix. Just look at the top-left 2x2-submatrix of M, then we have the diagonal-element $\small m_{1,1}=a+b+c $ and so it is not so surprising to get *a+b+c-1* in the diagonal of the LDU. I've just checked the determinant of the 2x2-matrix M using Pari/GP: $\small \begin{array} {lll} matdet([1,1;1,a+b+c]) \\ %1169 = a+b+c-1\end{array} $

Comment: Ah, I see the source of the discrepancy now. The left column and top row are completely 1 in my interpretation of the *M* matrix, while in the first answers they begin with the vectors of powers of *a* resp *b* - so I've just the unit-vectors prefixed. I've read the condition in the OP "if j=1 AND i=1" as "if j=1 and if i = 1" and then as "or". With that correction I get now the expected diagonal. The principal thought of my post concerning the LDU instead of LU-decomposition still stands; however. Thanks for the criticism!

Answer (score 0):

The identity follows almost immediately from the determinant [formula](http://qchu.wordpress.com/2009/11/17/the-lindstrom-gessel-viennot-lemma/) for counting non-intersecting paths:

- on one hand, the determinant counts the number of non-intersecting paths from points $a_i=(-i,0)$ to points $b_i=(0,i)$ on the lattice with $a$ edges going right, $b$ up, and $c$ up-right (for each vertex);
- on the other hand, to choose non-intersecting paths means to choose path from each of $n(n-1)/2$ "internal" vertices to it's upper-right neighbor — which can be done in exactly $ab+c$ ways: one can go either up-then-right or diagonally (for example, when $c=0$ there is, obviously, just one "geometric" path with some weight). **Upd:** that's not quite true; I'll try to fix it.

Comment: I don't see how this leads to an easy proof, but it gives a *very* intriguing combinatorial question. Counting non-crossing $n$-paths from the bottom of an $(n-1)\times(n-1)$ grid to its right side (the bottom-rightmost path having length $0$) with up/diagonal/right steps, by the number of diagonal steps, explain that there are $\binom{\tbinom{n}2}k$ solutions with $k$ diagonal steps. Even for $k=2$ and $k=\tbinom{n}2-2$ the solutions don't appear to correspond to $k$-subsets of some $\tbinom{n}2$-set in any obvious way.

Comment: For the record, this failed attempt at a proof inspired a discussion that I had with a collegue (Frédéric Bosio), and eventually he found a beautiful procedure to estabish a bijection, curently pubished as a [preprint on arXiv](http://arxiv.org/abs/1209.5373).