# What are some "natural" interpolations of the sequence $\small 0,1,1+2a,1+2a+3a^2,1+2a+3a^2+4a^3,\ldots $?

Tags: sequences-and-series, elementary-number-theory, interpolation

(This is a spin-off of a [recent question here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/86244))
In fiddling with the answer to that question I came to the set of sequences

$\qquad \small \begin{array} {llll}
A(1)=1,A(2)=1+2a,A(3)=1+2a+3a^2,A(4)=1+2a+3a^2+4a^3, \ldots \\
B(1)=1,B(2)=1+3a,B(3)=1+3a+6a^2,B(4)=1+3a+6a^2+10a^3, \ldots \\
C(1)=1,C(2)=1+4a,C(3)=1+4a+10a^2,C(4)=1+4a+10a^2+20a^3, \ldots \\
\ldots \\
 \end{array} $
with some indeterminate *a* .

We had the discussion often here in MSE, that interpolation to fractional indexes, say *A(1.5)=??* is arbitrary, considering, that an initial solution composed with any *1* -periodic function satisfies the condition. But here the embedding in a set of sequences, which are constructed from binomial-coefficients might suggest some "natural" interpolation, such as for

$\qquad \small K(1)=1, K(2)=1+a, K(3)=1+a+a^2, \ldots $

the interpolation $\small K(r) = {a^r-1 \over a-1}$ seems the most "natural" which even can smoothly be defined for *a=1*. This observation made me to refer to *"q-analogues"* $\small [r]_a $ in [my answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/86244/determinant-of-a-generalized-pascal-matrix/87008#87008) in the initiating MSE-question, but it's not obvious how to interpolate the shown sequences of higher orders **A** , **B** , **C** (I think they're not related to the *"q-binomial-analogues"* , for instance ).

**Q:** So what would be some "natural" interpolation to fractional indexes for the sequences **A**, **B**, **C**, and possibly in general for sequences generated in the obvious generalized manner?

---

Agreeing mostly with Henning's ansatz I got now the general form as
$$ A_m(n) = {1 \over (1-a)^m} - \sum_{k=0}^{m-1} \binom{n+m}{k}{a^{n+m-k} \over (1-a)^{m-k} } $$
I do not yet see, whether some examples of fractional indexes agree with the solutions of all three given answers so far, for instance: given *a=2.0* what is *A(1.5)*, *B(4/3)*, *C(7/5)*? With my programmed version I get now 
$\qquad \small  A(1.5)\sim 9.48528137424  $
$\qquad \small  B(4/3) \sim 11.8791929545  $
$\qquad \small  C(7/5) \sim 18.4386165488  $
(No interpolation for fractional *m* yet)

[update 2] the derivative-versions of Sivaram and Michael arrive at the same values so I think, all versions can be translated into each other and mutually support each other to express a "natural" interpolation.
[update 3] I had an index-error in my computation call. Corrected the numerical results.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is an attack leading to a closed forms for the $A$s and $B$s that can be evaluated for fractional $n$:

First, let $ A_n = \sum_{k=0}^n (k+1)a^k $.
For $n>0$ we can write
$$ A_n = a A_{n-1} + 1 + a + \cdots + a^n = a A_{n-1} + \frac{a^{n+1}-1}{a-1} $$
We can then use a base case of $A_0=1=\frac{a-1}{a-1}$ to unfold the entire recurrence into
\begin{align}
A_n &= \frac{1}{a-1}\Bigl( (a^{n+1}-1) + a(a^n-1) + a^2(a^{n-1}-1) + \cdots + a^n(a-1) \Bigr)
\\&= \frac{1}{a-1}\Bigl( (n+1)a^{n+1} - (1+a+\cdots+a^n) \Bigr)
\\&= \frac{1}{a-1}\Bigl( (n+1)a^{n+1} - \frac{a^{n+1}-1}{a-1} \Bigr)
\end{align}

We can push this into the $B$s by noting that
$$ B_n=A_n + a A_{n-1} + a^2 A_{n-2} + \cdots + a^n A_0 $$
so
\begin{align}
B_n &= \frac{1}{a-1}\left(\sum_{k=0}^n k+1\right)a^{n+1}
- \frac{1}{(a-1)^2} \Bigl( (a^{n+1}-1)+a(a^{n}-1)+\cdots+a^n(a-1) \Bigr)
\\&= \frac{1}{a-1} \frac{(n+1)(n+2)}{2} a^{n+1}
- \frac{1}{(a-1)^2} \Bigl( (n+1)a^{n+1} - (1+a+\cdots+a^n) \Bigr)
\\&= \frac{1}{a-1} \frac{(n+1)(n+2)}{2} a^{n+1}
- \frac{1}{(a-1)^2} (n+1)a^{n+1}
+ \frac{1}{(a-1)^3} (a^{n+1}-1)
\end{align}
A pattern is emerging ... I will leave the derivation for $C_n$ to the reader, but the only difficulty should be in keeping the algebra straight.

Comment: The alternating signs in the $B_n$ formula smell like there's some combinatoric inclusion-exclusion argument hiding somewhere beneath all this... or else I should just have written the denominators in terms of $1-a$ instead of $a-1$. Would it make any sense to treat the $a$ as a probability, I wonder?

Comment: Henning, I started slightly differently but now arrived at that same type of expressions. The general form should then be a sum, and the (1-a)-version indeed seems to be preferable as you suggested. I'll put that form into the question-box.

Comment: One (cosmetic) problem with using $1-a$ is that then all of the terms become _negative_ which looks strange. I think this approach should let you interpolate between, asy $C_{41}$ and $C_{42}$. Futher interpolation between $C_{41.7}$ and $D_{41.7}$ is a different matter, of course.

Comment: Well, the cosmetic problem can be explained easily. Remember, that the expansion of *1/(1-a)* is the geometric series of *a* written beginning at *1* along increasing powers out to infinity. From this *the infinite tail* is cutted by the subtraction, such that the finite leading part remains. Another problem becomes then visible: what does it then mean when *a>1* ? Analytic continuation required?

Comment: Nice general form. For any $a\ne 1$ the closed-form expressions here can just be evaluated, no analytic continuation needed. The case $a=1$ probably needs to be special-cased -- for integer $n$ it should be something like $\binom{n+C}{m+1}$ for some small $C$, which generalizes easily to fractional $n$. But it's not clear to me that it will then be continuous for $a$ on the $a=1$ line (except for integral $n$, of course).

Comment: Henning, I just used the explicite formula as given in my question taking the derivative for getting meaningful values for $\small a \to 1$. This comes out to be smooth for **A** and also to give continuous function values for fractional arguments of **A** . And because of the construction of that formula it looks convincingly easy that this generalizes to higher orders (**B**, **C**, ...). In short: for *a=1* we get just the binomial-coefficients at fractional arguments *n* .

Answer (score 4):

You have $K(r) = (a^r-1)/(a-1)$.

And ${d \over da} K(r) = 1 + 2a + \cdots + (r-1)a^{r-2} = A(r-1)$.

So it seems natural to define $A(r) = {d \over da} K(r+1)$, where $K(r)$ is defined as in your interpolation.

Similarly 
$$ {d^2 \over da^2} K(r) = 2 B(r-2) $$
and
$$ {d^3 \over da^3} K(r) = 6 C(r-3) $$
which we can solve for $B(r), C(r)$ to get
$$ B(r) = {1 \over 2} {d^2 \over da^2} K(r+2), C(r) = {1 \over 6} {d^3 \over da^3} K(r+3). $$

So I would define
$$ A_n(r) = {1 \over n!} {d^n \over da^n} K(r+n) $$
for any integer $n$ and real number $a$; this seems to be reasonably well-behaved. Here $A_1, A_2, A_3$ are your $A, B, C$.

(While I was writing this answer, Sivaram Ambikasaran's answer agreed. I am not sure if this is the same generalization or not.)

Also, does this extend to fractional $n$? I am not familiar enough with the fractional calculus to tell.

Comment: the "fractional n" (in the now extended question above this is the index *m*) makes me curious. I'm currently following Henning's explicite formula (with a slightly changed index *n*) and I'll try to get a clue how *m* could be interpolated in that framework.

Comment: Michael, after a handful of checks this derivative-formulation seems to agree with that other (explicite) formulation which I'd inserted in the original question. I just did numerical differentation with some fractional values *n* (in my notation, *r* in your notation here), so the methods seem to agree and so seem to mutually improve their application as candidates for the most "natural" concept of interpolation. Hmm.

Comment: Yes, what you have can definitely be made to work for arbitrary $n$. See my answer.

Answer (score 2):

One "natural" interpolation is along the following lines.
$$A(n) = \sum_{k=1}^{n} ka^{k-1} = \frac{d K_n(a)}{da}$$
$$B(n) = \sum_{k=1}^{n} \frac{k(k+1)}{2}a^{k-1} = \frac1{2!} \frac{d^2 K_{n+1}(a)}{da^2}$$
$$C(n) = \sum_{k=1}^{n} \frac{k(k+1)(k+2)}{6}a^{k-1} = \frac1{3!} \frac{d^3 K_{n+2}(a)}{da^3}$$
A generic "natural" interpolation would be $\displaystyle A_m(n) = \sum_{k=1}^{n} \binom{k+m}{m+1} a^{k-1}  = \frac1{(m+1)!} \frac{d^{m+1} K_{n+m}(a)}{da^{m+1}}$.

In our case, $A_0(n) = A(n)$, $A_1(n) = B(n)$, $A_2(n) = C(n)$ and so on...

Comment: thanks; but is it a misprint to have the *n* as suffix with the function **K** instead as an argument? This way I'm unsure whether I understand your evaluation correctly.

Answer (score 2):

I'll build from Michael's work (thanks for doing the heavy lifting!) and start with

$$A_n(r)=\frac1{n!}\frac{\mathrm d^n}{\mathrm da^n} \frac{a^{r+n}-1}{a-1}$$

Let's switch back to the series representation, and swap summation and differentiation:

$$A_n(r)=\frac1{n!}\sum_{k=0}^{r+n-1} \frac{\mathrm d^na^k}{\mathrm d a^n}$$

and make [a suitable replacement](http://functions.wolfram.com/ElementaryFunctions/Power/20/02/01/0001/):

$$A_n(r)=\frac1{n!}\sum_{k=0}^{r+n-1} \frac{k!a^{k-n}}{(k-n)!}=\frac1{n!}\sum_{k=-n}^{r-1} \frac{(k+n)!a^k}{k!}=\frac1{n!}\sum_{k=0}^{r-1} \frac{(k+n)!a^k}{k!}$$

where a reindexing and removal of extraneous zero terms was done in the last two steps.

The result can then be expressed as:

$$A_n(r)=\frac{\mathrm{I}_{1-a}(n+1,r)}{(1-a)^{n+1}}=\frac{1-\mathrm{I}_a(r,n+1)}{(1-a)^{n+1}}$$

where $\mathrm{I}_z(r,n)$ is a [regularized incomplete beta function](http://dlmf.nist.gov/8.17).

[In terms of the Gaussian hypergeometric function](http://dlmf.nist.gov/8.17.ii), we have

$$\begin{align*}
A_n(r)&=\frac{\mathrm{I}_{1-a}(n+1,r)}{(1-a)^{n+1}}\\
&=\frac{a^r}{(n+1)\mathrm{B}(n+1,r)}{}_2 F_1\left({{n+r+1, 1}\atop{n+2}}\mid1-a\right)\\
&=\binom{n+r}{n+1} {}_2 F_1\left({{1-r,n+1}\atop{n+2}}\mid1-a\right)
\end{align*}$$

where the third one is derived from the second one through the [Pfaff transformation](http://dlmf.nist.gov/15.8#E1). In particular, the third one gives the representation

$$A_n(r)=r\binom{n+r}{r}\sum_{k=0}^{r-1}\binom{r-1}{k}\frac{(a-1)^k}{n+k+1}$$

which is valid for arbitrary $n$ and nonnegative integer $r$.

Other hypergeometric representations can be derived.