# What is the determinant of the Pascal matrix $M_{ij} = \binom{2j+1}{i}$?

Tags: matrices, binomial-coefficients, determinant

For $0\le i,j\le N-1$, define $M_{ij} = \binom{2j+1}{i}$. For example, with $N=6$, we have
$$M_6=\left(\begin{array}{cccccc}1&1&1&1&1&1\\1&3&5&7&9&11\\0&3&10&21&36&55\\0&1&10&35&84&165\\0&0&5&35&126&330\\0&0&1&21&126&462\\\end{array}\right)$$
For the first few $N$s, I have $\det(M_2)=2$, $\det(M_3)=8$, $\det(M_4)=64$, $\det(M_5)=1024$, $\det(M_6)=32768$, so it is easy to conjecture
$$\det(M_N) = 2^{\binom{n}{2}}$$
This would suggest an induction approach, perhaps similar to the one proposed by Marc in this [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/86244/determinant-of-a-generalized-pascal-matrix). If the same approach worked in this case, we could apply some elimination matrices to reduce $M_N$ to something of the form
$$M_N=\left(\begin{array}{cc} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 2M_{N-1}\end{array}\right)$$
at which point induction would finish the proof. However, the elimination matrices required to obtain this reduction are not as easy to find given that the elements of the matrix satisfy the recursion
$$M_{ij}=M_{i,j-1}+2M_{i-1,j-1}+M_{i-2,j-1}$$
where the last term is the one which causes most of the problems. Another idea would be to try to row reduce $M_N$ to a lower triangular matrix. For instance, with $N=6$, we would have:
$$M_6 \to \left(\begin{array}{cccccc}1&1&1&1&1&1\\0&2&4&6&8&10\\0&0&4&12&24&40\\0&0&0&8&32&80\\0&0&0&0&16&80\\0&0&0&0&0&32\\\end{array}\right)$$
from which the result is readily apparent. Dividing the $n$th row by $2^n$ reveals a Pascal matrix, so I was hoping one could transform the Pascal matrix to only include its odd-numbered columns. However, I have not been able to come up with the required manipulations. Is there something trivial I am missing?

Comment: Excellent problem. I have some ideas but I have not worked it out yet. I tend to do LU decomposition on the Pascal matrix $M_n$. Here, $U_{ij} = 2^i \binom j i$. The $U_{ij}$ coefficients are inspired by your last matrix (whose bottom right element is 32). Therefore, the only thing left to do is to calculate the binomial inversion $f$ such that $\sum\limits_{k=0}^i 2^k \binom j k f(i, k) = \binom {2j+1} k$. I think DTFT might work as it is a "convolution" but I have NOT finished it yet.

Comment: The inverse matrix $U^{-1}$ of $U$ is defined as $U^{-1}_{ij} = (-1)^{i+j}2^{-j}\binom j i$.

Comment: @Muse_China this is a good idea. I think all that is required now is to prove that $MU^{-1}$ is lower triangular with ones on the diagonal.

Comment: I have proved it. Please wait for my answer and I will upload it before tonight!

Comment: @Muse_China I also found a solution inspired by your idea that I posted to organize the argument in my head. I used the "coefficient of" operator rather than DTFT. But feel free to post your answer and I will gladly accept it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, consider the $LU$ decomposition of the Pascal matrix $M=LU$, where $L$ is a lower-triangular matrix and $U$ is an upper-triangular matrix. Inspired by the OP's work, we set $U_{ij} = 2^i \binom j i$. This proof uses two useful lemmas in Donald Knuth's book [The Art of Computer Programming (TAOCP)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Art_of_Computer_Programming).

$\textbf{Lemma 1}$: Let $j$ be a positive integer and $b_0, b_1,...,b_j$ be real numbers. Then

$\sum\limits_{k=0}^j (-1)^{j+k} \binom j k (\sum\limits_{i=0}^j b_ik^i) = j!b_j$.

Proof of Lemma 1 is easy. We can recursively consider the binomial sum with respect to $i$:

$\sum\limits_{k=0}^j (-1)^{j+k} \binom j k \Pi_{t=0}^{i-1}(k - m)$

and show that

$\sum\limits_{k=0}^j (-1)^{j+k} \binom j k k^i = \begin{cases}
        0, & i<j;\\
        j!, & i=j.\\
        \end{cases} $

$\textbf{Lemma 2}$: Let $i, j, k$ be natural integers and $j \geq i$, then $\sum\limits_{k}(-1)^{i+k}\binom k i \binom j k = \delta_{ij}$. $\delta_{ij}$ is the well known Kronecker symbol which is $1$ if $i = j$ and $0$ if $i \neq j$.

$\textbf{Proof to Lemma 2}$:

First, $\sum\limits_k (-1)^{i+k} \binom k i \binom j k = (-1)^{i-j}\sum\limits_k(-1)^{j+k}\binom k i \binom j k$.

Now, we treat $\binom k i$ as a polynomial of $k$. The $\binom k i$ refers to $\sum\limits_{i=0}^j b_ik^i$ in Lemma 1. If $i < j$, then the coefficient of $k^j$ is $0$. Otherwise, if $i = j$, the coefficient of $k^j$ is $\frac{1}{j!}$. Therefore, according to Lemma 1, $\sum\limits_k (-1)^{i+k} \binom k i \binom j k = (-1)^{i-j} j! (\text{Coefficient of}\quad k^j \quad\text{in the polynomial} \quad \binom k i) = \delta_{ij}$.

$\textbf{Proof of Lemma 2 ends.}$

Following Lemma 2, we get $(U^{-1})_{ij} = (-1)^{i+j}2^{-j}\binom j i$. To be honest, I calculate $U^{-1}$ using Mathematica Pro 12 before proving it.

The next step is to calculate $MU^{-1}$. We have:

$L_{ij} = (MU^{-1})_{ij} = \sum\limits_{k}M_{ik}(U^{-1})_{kj} = \sum\limits_{k}(-1)^{j+k}2^{-j}\binom {2k+1} {i}\binom j k$. (1)

Here, we want to show that $L$ is a lower-triangular matrix with all its diagonal elements being $1$, i.e.,

$L_{ij} = \begin{cases}
        0, & i<j;\\
        1, & i=j.\\
        \end{cases}$ (2)

To prove (2), very similar to the proof of Lemma 2, we treat the binomial coefficient $\binom {2k+1} i$ in Eq. (1) as a polynomial of $k$. We treat the variable $j$ in Eq. (1) the same as Lemma 1. For the case where $i=j$, the coefficient of $k_j$ is $\frac{2^j}{j!}$. For the case where $i < j$, the coefficient of $k_j$ is $0$. Therefore, Eq. (2) is true and $L=MU^{-1}$ is a lower-triangular matrix with all its diagonal elements being $1$, hence $det(L) = 1$.

Finally, $\det(M) = \det(U) = 2^{\binom n 2}$.

Comment: It hadn't ocurred to me to look at $\binom {k}{j}$ as a polynomial in $k$. Nice proof!

Answer (score 3):

Inspired by Muse_China's comments under my question, we can define $U_{ij} = 2^i \binom{j}{i}$, which factors as $\text{diag}(1,2,2^2,\cdots, 2^{N-1})P_N$ where $P_N = \binom{j}{i}$ is the $N\times N$ Pascal matrix with inverse $P_N^{-1} = (-1)^{i+j}\binom{j}{i}$. It follows that $U_{ij}^{-1} = (-1)^{i+j}2^{-j}\binom{j}{i}$. If $U$ were the upper triangular factor in the LU decomposition of $M$, we must have $L=MU^{-1}$, so we must show $L$ is lower triangular and has $1$'s on the diagonal. Therefore, compute
$$\begin{align}
L_{ij} &= \sum_{k=0}^{N-1} M_{ik}U_{kj}^{-1} = \sum_{k=0}^{N-1}(-1)^{k+j}2^{-j} \binom{2k+1}{i}\binom{j}{k}
    \\
    &=(-2)^{-j}\sum_{k=0}^{j}(-1)^{k} \binom{2k+1}{i}\binom{j}{k}
\end{align}
$$
Introduce the "coefficient of" operator $[x^i]$ as $[x^i]\left(\sum_{j=0}^N a_jx^j\right)=a_i$ which is evidently linear and use it to re-write the $\binom{2k+1}i$ term above as $[x^i](1+x)^{2k+1}$. This simplifies the expression for $L$ to
$$
\begin{align}
L_{ij} &= (-2)^{-j}[x^i]\sum_{k=0}^{j}(-1)^{k} (1+x)^{2k+1}\binom{j}{k}
\\
&=(-2)^{-j}[x^i](1+x)\sum_{k=0}^{j}(-1)^{k} (1+x)^{2k}\binom{j}{k}
\\
&=(-2)^{-j}[x^i](1+x)(1-(1+x)^2)^j=2^{-j}[x^i](1+x)x^j(2+x)^j
\\
&=2^{-j}[x^{i-j}](1+x)(2+x)^j
\end{align}
$$
In particular, if $j> i$, the coefficient of operator picks up a $0$, and when $i=j$, it is clear that $[x^0](1+x)(2+x)^j=2^j$, and so $\det(L)=1$ and $\det(M_n)=\det(U)=2^{\binom{n}{2}}$.

Comment: Now that you have proved it, please allow me to finish my proof when I have more spared time. Nice proof!

Comment: @Muse_China No problem, your suggestions were very helpful and I look forward to seeing your argument!

Comment: My proof is much longer and more complicated than yours. I think your answer would be better.